# Create a dynamic group by Query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a form with 4 checkbox for grouping , when I want to create LINQ dynamic query in where clause, it is very easy to use something like this :

```
  query = query.where(x=>x.blah == blahblah).asQueryable();
```

but I can't simulate this type of coding for Group by clause. I need something like this :

```
if(blah1==true)
    query = query.GroupBy(x=>x.Blah1).select(smthing);
if(blah2==true)
    query = query.GroupBy(x=>x.Blah2).select(smthing);
if(blah3==true)
    query = query.GroupBy(x=>x.Blah3).select(smthing);
 ....
```

How can I do this kind of query? some post in stackoverflow show misunderstanding code like Expression> . Please show [me](http://translateyar.ir) an easy and applicable way.

Comment: When you say you can't simulate, you mean you get a compilation error ? Could you please post an example, an instance of your form and how the correct query should be -in terms of that you want to fetch with the execution of your query ? Thanks

Comment: Using `System.Linq.Dynamic` package you can create such dynamic group by, for example `query.GroupBy("new (Id, Name)", "it")` but I'm not sure how you are going to use the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is not the correct way of doing things, but using reflection does thing. Hence, all you need is to determine property name and pass it to `GroupBy`.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Wage { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() =>
        $"Name: {Name}, Wage: {Wage}, Age: {Age}";
}

var list = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Name1", Wage = 1, Age = 1},
    new Person { Name = "Name1", Wage = 2, Age = 2},
    new Person { Name = "Name2", Wage = 2, Age = 2},
    new Person { Name = "Name3", Wage = 2, Age = 2},
    new Person { Name = "Name3", Wage = 2, Age = 2},
    new Person { Name = "Name4", Wage = 2, Age = 2},
    new Person { Name = "Name4", Wage = 2, Age = 2}
};

var x = list.GroupBy(p => p.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(p));

foreach(var z in x)
{
    WriteLine(z.Key);
    foreach(var p in z)
    {
        WriteLine("\t" + p);
    }
}

/*
    Output:

Name1
      Name: Name1, Wage: 1, Age: 1
      Name: Name1, Wage: 2, Age: 2
Name2
      Name: Name2, Wage: 2, Age: 2
Name3
      Name: Name3, Wage: 2, Age: 2
      Name: Name3, Wage: 2, Age: 2
Name4
      Name: Name4, Wage: 2, Age: 2
      Name: Name4, Wage: 2, Age: 2
*/
```

Comment: @mahdimoghimi This is what I'm saying - you pass property name to `GroupBy` - and reflection does the work. For instance: `p => p.GetType().GetProperty("facultyid").GetValue(p)`.

Comment: Johny Could u please Show me last nested foreach as LINQ?

Comment: I want to dynamically fill my model by your Grouping . for e.g  I have only FacultyId and studentCount. I have also studylevelId but it not ticked first , only must show Count of Students based on FacultyId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185684/discussion-between-johnyl-and-mahdi-moghimi).